# How to convert "day, hh:mm:ss" format to hh:mm in odoo v10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I am beginner in odoo.

I want to calculate of two datetimes, my code as below

```
d1 = datetime.strptime("2021-07-12 03:24:08", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d2 = datetime.strptime("2021-07-10 08:35:26", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

x = d1-d2
```

the result is **1 day, 18:48:42**

but i need the result with format **hour:minute (hh:mm)**, how to convert the 1st result into hh:mm?

I appreciate your advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert it as below:

```
d1 = datetime.strptime("2021-07-12 03:24:08", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
d2 = datetime.strptime("2021-07-10 08:35:26", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

# get days
days = (d1 -d2).days
# get seconds
seconds= (d1 -d2).seconds
# get hours
hours = seconds//3600
# get minutes
minutes = (seconds//60)%60

total_hrs = days * 24 + hours
total_diff = str(total_hrs) +":" + str(minutes)
print(total_diff)
```

**Output**:

```
42:48
```